# Logistic Regression-Linear Features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, data-mining

I was reading this post on quora https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-different-classification-algorithms 
It states here that :-"Logistic regression is a pretty well-behaved classification algorithm that can be trained **as long as you expect your features to be roughly linear** and the problem to be linearly separable"
What does it mean to have features linear?. Another place this comes up in the post is "Tree Ensembles have different advantages over LogisticR. One main advantage is that they **do not expect linear features**"
I am not sure what does linear features mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term they used may not be standard term. I guess it means the decision boundary can be roughly approximated by a heyperplane. (a line in 2D space). Here are two examples for "linear feature" (A) or not (B) in 2 dimensional sapce.

[image]

Here is my answer to a very related question, which may be helpful for you.

[Do all machine learning algorithms separate data linearly?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215696/do-all-machine-learning-algorithms-separate-data-linearly/215763#215763)

Comment: Thank you. So i am guessing this --->"You can do some feature engineering to turn most non-linear features into linear pretty easily"  would be taking something like log transformations to get "linear features".

Comment: @AkashMehta yes, and the link I provided is on this topic: the OP was trying to ask if all the machine learning algorithm is doing this transformation to linear

Comment: Note that in case B you can introduce a new, linear feature: The distance from the centre!

Answer (score 3):

For another view of linear separability (assuming that's what linear features means) imagine you have a simple dataset with `sex` as a binary, categorical covariate and `results` as a binary outcome of some experiment.

```
sex   outcome
m     1  
m     1
m     0
f     0
f     0
f     0
```

For binary response data (i.e. like this), it's common to use a logistic regression to model, among other things, the probability of `outcome = 1` given `sex`. However, what if your input was `sex = f`. Then:

$$P(\text{outcome} = 1 | \text{sex} = f) = 0$$

because we have no training examples of this ever happening. In this way, we say that the data is linearly separable per @hxd1011's image above.

In fact, if you tried to fit a logistic regression you'd likely get an error because the MLE estimates tend to infinity (unless your computer software has a parameter which stops the algorithm, usually [IRLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), from continuing to looks for a minimum). If you get data like this and want to use a logistic regression, you can look into [penalized logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216187/what-is-penalized-logistic-regression). [Here is nice write](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/cs769/lr.pdf) up about it.